# is there a way to have array_column() keep the $input array key?

Tags: php, arrays

Suppose I have an array of records, keyed by some ID, and I use the `array_column()` function to extract one piece of data from each record.

```
$records = array(
    1234 => array(
        'first_name' => 'John',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
    ),
    4567 => array(
        'first_name' => 'Sally',
        'last_name' => 'Smith',
    ),
);
```

The result from `array_column($input, 'first_name')` is a numerically indexed array (with new keys 0, 1, ...). Is there a way of keeping the keys from the input array?

Comment: `$newArray = array_combine(array_keys($records), array_column($records, 'first_name'));`

Answer (score 1):

```
array_map(function ($r) { return $r['first_name']; }, $records)
```

will do (for your precise case).

It is more or less equivalent to this (PHP 7+):

```
(function () use ($records) {
    $result = [];
    foreach ($records as $key => $r) {
        $result[$key] = $r['first_name'];
    }
    return $result;
)()
```

Answer (score 0):

When the id would also be available in the data array's you could use the third argument of `array_column`.

For example:
`array_column($records, 'first_name', 'id');`

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clear - the desired data isn't available in the arrays, only as the key.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple function I often use:

```
function array_column_with_keys(array $array, string $column): array {
    return array_combine(
        array_keys($array), 
        array_column($array, $column));
}
```

So using your example array,

`var_export(array_column_with_keys($records, 'first_name'));`

will return:

```
array (
  1234 => 'John',
  4567 => 'Sally',
)
```